# Swift: Unwrapping a dictionary messes up the order of the values inside of it

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am receiving JSON which then I'm storing in a dictionary variable `menus`. However, the problem is after unwrapping the data, the order of the "menus" gets messed up. And so they do not get displayed in order in the UI.
[image]

```
  print("INSIDE CMSessionManger.login result[menus]: ", result["menus"]!)
                                /*
                                 INSIDE CMSessionManger.login result[menus]:  {
                                     1 =     {
                                         id = 1;
                                         label = Accueil;
                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                     };
                                     2 =     {
                                         id = 2;
                                         label = "Mes favoris";
                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                     };
                                     3 =     {
                                         id = 3;
                                         label = "Les s\U00e9lections";
                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                     };
                                     4 =     {
                                         id = 4;
                                         label = "Acc\U00e8s illimit\U00e9";
                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                     };
                                 }
                                 **/
                                print("INSIDE CMSessionManger.login  type(of: result[menus]!: ",  type(of: result["menus"]!))
                                
                                if let menus = result["menus"] as? [String: Any]{
                                                                   print("INSIDE CMSessionManger.login Setting menus")
                                                                   print("INSIDE CMSessionManger.login menus: ",  menus)
                                                                  /*
                                                                     INSIDE CMSessionManger.login menus:  ["2": {
                                                                         id = 2;
                                                                         label = "Mes favoris";
                                                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                                                     }, "4": {
                                                                         id = 4;
                                                                         label = "Acc\U00e8s illimit\U00e9";
                                                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                                                     }, "1": {
                                                                         id = 1;
                                                                         label = Accueil;
                                                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                                                     }, "3": {
                                                                         id = 3;
                                                                         label = "Les s\U00e9lections";
                                                                         maxNumberPerPage = 20;
                                                                     }]
                                                                     **/
                                                                 
                                                                    
                                                               }
```

I really don't understand why would a simple unwrap change the order of the dictionary values.

Comment: A dictionary doesn't have order, it's key access, not index access.

Comment: Okay, but how can I unwrap it without losing the 'order' in which they came?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html You don't care about the order, what you want is `menus["1"]`, or menus["2"], etc, because that's the key.

Comment: @AhmedGhrib I don't think you get it: dictionaries have *no defined order*. The apparent ordering you see when you see when you iterate your dictionary can easily change after things are added/removed, after it resizes. The same dictionary literal will even have different ordering, because the program's hash seed will have (intentionally) changed. See https://forums.swift.org/t/psa-the-stdlib-now-uses-randomly-seeded-hash-values/10789

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are unordered collections. There is no way to guarantee that you will get the items back in the same order in which you add them. It looks like your keys are numbers, and are repeated in the "id" key/value pair of each dictionary entry. If you really want the data to have a specific order, why not send the items in an array?

You could use the Dictinary.values property to get the entries in your dictionary into an array, and then sort those entries by their `id` values.

Here is sample code that does that:

```
let aDict:[Int: [String:Any]] = [
    1 :
        ["id": 1,
         "label": "Accueil",
         "maxNumberPerPage":20 ],
    
    2 : ["id": 2,
         "label": "Mes favoris",
         "maxNumberPerPage": 20
    ],
    3 : ["id": 3,
         "label": "Les sélections",
         "maxNumberPerPage": 20
    ]
]

let values = aDict.values.sorted{
    ($0["id"] as! Int) < ($1["id"] as! Int) }


values.forEach {print($0)}
```

Note that the code above will crash if the contents of any of the inner dictionaries does not contain a key/value pair with the key "id" and with a value that is an `Int`. Production code that parsed JSON would need input validation.